# Array Formula breaks when trying referencing another array formula value output

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have attached a copy of a [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s_-0vRgWIVN1-0J2ur2RWtcoxhCFy8CzOYrqhg0oBoE/edit?usp=sharing) I'm working in.

What I'm trying to do is build an array formula that outputs an "Overall Total" value in column J, which is the sum of what Column E cell that aligns with the row the formula is being calculated in plus the next 3 cells below in column E only when 2 conditions are both met. Each condition is looking at a particular Column and trying to match the cell of that column in questions plus and the next 3 cells below it to all match.

Knowing that I can't directly do IF/IFS with "And" or "Or" in an array formula. I have created Column F "Date Match" to check for the first condition in column D "Date" and output 1 or 0 as a true/false if the 4 cells in question match, and Column H "Scan Match" to check the 2nd condition of column C "Scan" and output 1 or 0 for true/false if the 4 cells in questions match.

I have the array formula in column J working, but only if I use a non-array formula in column F and column H. IF F or H are set up in an array, it breaks my formula in column J.

I need columns F, H, and J in an array because this sheet receives 16 new data entries from the google form it's linked to per day and then that get multiplied many times over base on how many locations we have. So, having to come in and drag down rows is not feasible.

How can I either get column F and H in an array the doesn't break Column J or create an array formula in column J that checks for the 2 conditions and returns the value if true or leaves the cell blank if false? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73808521/19529694) it ueses arrayformula, give it a try.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This method combines your date match, scan match, and total column into one array formula.

```
=ArrayFormula(((D2:D=D3:D)*(D3:D=D4:D)*(D4:D=D5:D)*(C2:C=C3:C)*(C3:C=C4:C)*(C4:C=C5:C))*(E2:E+E3:E+E4:E+E5:E))
```

Since you need Date Match to be true and Scan Match to be true, you can combine those two columns using the same multiplication method you've already used. Then you multiply that value (it will be 0 if false and 1 if true) by the sum of the current row and the next three rows in column E (like you've already done in the Overall Total column) to get the total. I've included the ISBLANK test to prevent 0s from populating the full length of the column.

[image]

Comment: If it's important to have null values in the Overall Total column instead of the 0s, then use this formula: =ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),,IF(ISERR(1/((D2:D=D3:D)*(D3:D=D4:D)*(D4:D=D5:D)*(C2:C=C3:C)*(C3:C=C4:C)*(C4:C=C5:C))),"",(D2:D=D3:D)*(D3:D=D4:D)*(D4:D=D5:D)*(C2:C=C3:C)*(C3:C=C4:C)*(C4:C=C5:C)*(E2:E+E3:E+E4:E+E5:E))))

Comment: Thank you so much! this is exactly what I needed and was hoping to get to. An all in 1 formula that checks both conditions, totals the 4 cell needed when the conditions are met, and leaves the other false cells blank. I have another array formula in the sheet that gives me the totals from some other values I need but isn't laving blank cells like I want, so I get the big long ugly string of zero's past the last entry. I'm pretty sure your formula will help me fix that as well. Again, Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

**Use this formula**
Since I am aware that you want a formula that does not require movement, here it is.

Paste it `F2`

### With Arrayformula

```
=ArrayFormula(LAMBDA(vv,s, IF(s<>1,,VLOOKUP(vv, 
                                  { QUERY(UNIQUE(vv), " Select * where Col1 is not null "),
                                    BYROW(QUERY(UNIQUE(vv), " Select * where Col1 is not null "), LAMBDA(c, SUMIF(vv, "="&c, E2:E)))}, 2,1)))(
              ARRAYFORMULA(LAMBDA(u, LAMBDA(l, IF(A2:A="",,VLOOKUP(ROW(E2:E),FILTER({ROW(E2:E),l},l<>""),2,TRUE)))(IF(u="",,COUNTIFS(u, "<>", ROW(E2:E), "<="&ROW(E2:E)))))(ArrayFormula(IF(
 IF(A2:A="",, { IF(D2:D="",,BYROW(
 VLOOKUP(ROW(D2:D), 
         { ArrayFormula(ROW(D2:D)),BYROW(ROW(D2:D), LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), , BYROW(SEQUENCE(4,1,x), LAMBDA(v, FILTER(D2:D, ROW(D2:D)=v))))))}, 2,0), 
 LAMBDA(g, LAMBDA(r, SUMPRODUCT(BYROW( r, LAMBDA(v, lambda(x,y,INDEX(x, y))(r,1)=v)))=4)(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(g, CHAR(10)))))))*
                IF(C2:C="",, BYROW(
 VLOOKUP(ROW(C2:C), 
         { ArrayFormula(ROW(C2:C)),BYROW(ROW(C2:C), LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), , BYROW(SEQUENCE(4,1,x), LAMBDA(v, FILTER(C2:C, ROW(C2:C)=v))))))}, 2,0), 
 LAMBDA(g, LAMBDA(r, SUMPRODUCT(BYROW( r, LAMBDA(v, lambda(x,y,INDEX(x, y))(r,1)=v)))=4)(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(g, CHAR(10)))))))})<>1,,1)))),
              ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",, { IF(D2:D="",,BYROW(
 VLOOKUP(ROW(D2:D), 
         { ArrayFormula(ROW(D2:D)),BYROW(ROW(D2:D), LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), , BYROW(SEQUENCE(4,1,x), LAMBDA(v, FILTER(D2:D, ROW(D2:D)=v))))))}, 2,0), 
 LAMBDA(g, LAMBDA(r, SUMPRODUCT(BYROW( r, LAMBDA(v, lambda(x,y,INDEX(x, y))(r,1)=v)))=4)(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(g, CHAR(10)))))))*
                IF(C2:C="",, BYROW(
 VLOOKUP(ROW(C2:C), 
         { ArrayFormula(ROW(C2:C)),BYROW(ROW(C2:C), LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), , BYROW(SEQUENCE(4,1,x), LAMBDA(v, FILTER(C2:C, ROW(C2:C)=v))))))}, 2,0), 
 LAMBDA(g, LAMBDA(r, SUMPRODUCT(BYROW( r, LAMBDA(v, lambda(x,y,INDEX(x, y))(r,1)=v)))=4)(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(g, CHAR(10)))))))}))))
```

[image]

**Sources**

**Notes**
If you want to delve deep, consider looking at the previous [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73808521/timeline#history_2d94c747-6709-48ad-9d1e-5228a0bef80d).

### Let's make it a named function (˘◡˘ )

See how to [using Google Sheets new formulas](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12504534?hl=en-GB)

[image]

**Paste** this in formula definition

```
=ArrayFormula(
  LAMBDA(
    vv,
    s,
    IF(
      s <> 1,
      ,
      VLOOKUP(
        vv,
{            QUERY(
              UNIQUE(
                vv
              ),
              "Select*whereCol1isnotnull"
            ),
            BYROW(
              QUERY(
                UNIQUE(
                  vv
                ),
                "Select*whereCol1isnotnull"
              ),
              LAMBDA(
                c,
                SUMIF(
                  vv,
                  "=" & c,
                  range
                )
              )
            )},
        2,
        1
      )
    )
  ) (
    ARRAYFORMULA(
      LAMBDA(
        u,
        LAMBDA(
          l,
          IF(
            key = "",
            ,
            VLOOKUP(
              ROW(
                range
              ),
              FILTER(
{                    ROW(
                      range
                    ),
                    l},
                l <> ""
              ),
              2,
              TRUE
            )
          )
        ) (
          IF(
            u = "",
            ,
            COUNTIFS(
              u,
              "<>",
              ROW(
                range
              ),
              "<=" &
              ROW(
                range
              )
            )
          )
)
      ) (
        ArrayFormula(
          IF(
            IF(
              key = "",
              ,
{                  IF(
                    date = "",
                    ,
                    BYROW(
                      VLOOKUP(
                        ROW(
                          date
                        ),
{                            ArrayFormula(
                              ROW(
                                date
                              )
                            ),
                            BYROW(
                              ROW(
                                date
                              ),
                              LAMBDA(
                                x,
                                TEXTJOIN(
                                  CHAR(
                                    10
                                  ),
                                  ,
                                  BYROW(
                                    SEQUENCE(
                                      4,
                                      1,
                                      x
                                    ),
                                    LAMBDA(
                                      v,
                                      FILTER(
                                        date,
                                        ROW(
                                          date
                                        ) = v
                                      )
                                    )
                                  )
                                )
                              )
                            )},
                        2,
                        0
                      ),
                      LAMBDA(
                        g,
                        LAMBDA(
                          r,
                          SUMPRODUCT(
                            BYROW(
                              r,
                              LAMBDA(
                                v,
                                lambda(
                                  x,
                                  y,
                                  INDEX(
                                    x,
                                    y
                                  )
                                ) (
                                  r , 1
) = v
                              )
                            )
                          ) = 4
                        ) (
                          TRANSPOSE(
                            SPLIT(
                              g,
                              CHAR(
                                10
                              )
                            )
                          )
)
                      )
                    )
                  ) *
                  IF(
                    scan = "",
                    ,
                    BYROW(
                      VLOOKUP(
                        ROW(
                          scan
                        ),
{                            ArrayFormula(
                              ROW(
                                scan
                              )
                            ),
                            BYROW(
                              ROW(
                                scan
                              ),
                              LAMBDA(
                                x,
                                TEXTJOIN(
                                  CHAR(
                                    10
                                  ),
                                  ,
                                  BYROW(
                                    SEQUENCE(
                                      4,
                                      1,
                                      x
                                    ),
                                    LAMBDA(
                                      v,
                                      FILTER(
                                        scan,
                                        ROW(
                                          scan
                                        ) = v
                                      )
                                    )
                                  )
                                )
                              )
                            )},
                        2,
                        0
                      ),
                      LAMBDA(
                        g,
                        LAMBDA(
                          r,
                          SUMPRODUCT(
                            BYROW(
                              r,
                              LAMBDA(
                                v,
                                lambda(
                                  x,
                                  y,
                                  INDEX(
                                    x,
                                    y
                                  )
                                ) (
                                  r , 1
) = v
                              )
                            )
                          ) = 4
                        ) (
                          TRANSPOSE(
                            SPLIT(
                              g,
                              CHAR(
                                10
                              )
                            )
                          )
)
                      )
                    )
                  )}
            ) <> 1,
            ,
            1
          )
        )
)
    ) ,
    ArrayFormula(
      IF(
        key = "",
        ,
{            IF(
              date = "",
              ,
              BYROW(
                VLOOKUP(
                  ROW(
                    date
                  ),
{                      ArrayFormula(
                        ROW(
                          date
                        )
                      ),
                      BYROW(
                        ROW(
                          date
                        ),
                        LAMBDA(
                          x,
                          TEXTJOIN(
                            CHAR(
                              10
                            ),
                            ,
                            BYROW(
                              SEQUENCE(
                                4,
                                1,
                                x
                              ),
                              LAMBDA(
                                v,
                                FILTER(
                                  date,
                                  ROW(
                                    date
                                  ) = v
                                )
                              )
                            )
                          )
                        )
                      )},
                  2,
                  0
                ),
                LAMBDA(
                  g,
                  LAMBDA(
                    r,
                    SUMPRODUCT(
                      BYROW(
                        r,
                        LAMBDA(
                          v,
                          lambda(
                            x,
                            y,
                            INDEX(
                              x,
                              y
                            )
                          ) (
                            r , 1
) = v
                        )
                      )
                    ) = 4
                  ) (
                    TRANSPOSE(
                      SPLIT(
                        g,
                        CHAR(
                          10
                        )
                      )
                    )
)
                )
              )
            ) *
            IF(
              scan = "",
              ,
              BYROW(
                VLOOKUP(
                  ROW(
                    scan
                  ),
{                      ArrayFormula(
                        ROW(
                          scan
                        )
                      ),
                      BYROW(
                        ROW(
                          scan
                        ),
                        LAMBDA(
                          x,
                          TEXTJOIN(
                            CHAR(
                              10
                            ),
                            ,
                            BYROW(
                              SEQUENCE(
                                4,
                                1,
                                x
                              ),
                              LAMBDA(
                                v,
                                FILTER(
                                  scan,
                                  ROW(
                                    scan
                                  ) = v
                                )
                              )
                            )
                          )
                        )
                      )},
                  2,
                  0
                ),
                LAMBDA(
                  g,
                  LAMBDA(
                    r,
                    SUMPRODUCT(
                      BYROW(
                        r,
                        LAMBDA(
                          v,
                          lambda(
                            x,
                            y,
                            INDEX(
                              x,
                              y
                            )
                          ) (
                            r , 1
) = v
                        )
                      )
                    ) = 4
                  ) (
                    TRANSPOSE(
                      SPLIT(
                        g,
                        CHAR(
                          10
                        )
                      )
                    )
)
                )
              )
            )}
      )
    )
)
)
```

[image: using Google Sheets new formulas]

### How to use

[image: Create and use named functions]

Used functions: Checkout [Google Sheets function list](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en-GB)
`ARRAYFORMULA` - `LAMBDA` - `IF` - `VLOOKUP` - `QUERY` - `UNIQUE` - `BYROW` - `SUMIF` - `ROW`

Comment: In case you didn't know, this table, when copied is tab separated and when Ctrl+V'd, automatically fills up the cells in Google sheets.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to share all this! I've just recently seen "named function" option and I will be taking advantage of since this formula will actually be repeated across another dozen or so tabs on this sheet. In regards to your method. Maybe I'm missing something, I'm newish posting here, but the overall totals column is not adding up the matching 4 values. Either way, I'm learning a ton and really appreciate your time and knowledge sharing.

Comment: @ChadO. It takes a long time to output due to a lot of calculations across the whole column many times wait 5 or 10 secs, please share your result. The overall totals will output 2 result as you showed in your question, confirm the desired output if diffrent than what you want.

Comment: @ChadO. the answer is updated take a look.